# Не отображается реклама AdMob после загрузки с Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, admob

Появилась такая проблема. Подключил рекламу AdMob баннеры, межстраничные обьявления, просмотр за вознаграждение. С тестовой рекламой все работает корректно, мало того все работает с обычной рекламой если установить приложение через сброшеный apk файл. Но при загрузке приложения с Google play рекламы нет. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Та же проблема, через сутки после публикации на google play. У Вас получилось решить?